# Значение слова ДУНЪИ в Советской исторической энциклопедии

Tags: значение-слов, ономастика, существительные, значение, имена-нарицательные

В пятом томе Советской исторической энциклопедии стоит короткое непонятное объяснение:

> ДУНЪИ - см. И.

[image: фото страницы СИЭ]

Что это означает, "смотри И."?

И главное, Дунъи - это имя нарицательное или собственное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это означает ровно то, что написано: смотрите, то есть, статью с заголовком "И".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]